# web rtc just audio works from android to ios

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc

I am using a webRTC demo from this site

https://appr.tc/
[source](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc)

it works from computer browser to ios mobile/safari (video-audio)

it also works from android to android (video-audio)

but from android to iOS (safari), I get no video, just sound

with below error:

[image]

```
WSS->C: {"msg":"{\"type\":\"candidate\",\"label\":0,\"id\":\"audio\",\"candidate\":\"\"}","error":""}

addIceCandidate: OperationError: Expect line: candidate:<candidate-str>
```

how can I have the webRTC video call working from iOS/safari to android?

Comment: I've just reached the same issue with iOS (`addIceCandidate: OperationError: Expect line: candidate:<candidate-str>`) on an experiment of mine and very interested in a solution to this. Did you figure this out?

Comment: This page with different web platform tests might help: https://diff-3-numbers-dot-wptdashboard-staging.appspot.com/interop/webrtc/RTCPeerConnection-addIceCandidate.html